# Why do I get connecting the library path in Django?

Tags: python, django

When I adding the library path in app general of urls, send me the next message: "E0611:No name 'path' in module 'django.urls'" and "E0611:No name 're_path' in module 'django.urls'".

It is the code in generals urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,re_path
from django.urls import include,path
from homepage.views import homepage

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^',include('homepage.urls')),
]

urlpatterns +=[
    re_path(r'home/',include('homepage.urls'))
]
```

The version I using is v2.1

Thanks for you help me.

Comment: What version of django are you using? `path` is available since version 2.

Comment: I using the version 2.1

Answer (score 1):

In official documentation they explain cool.you need to study documentation more

```
#Example of using re_path

from django.urls import include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio, name='bio'),
    re_path(r'^weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
] 

 #Example of using path

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view'),
    path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
    path('articles/<slug:title>/', views.article, name='article-detail'),
    path('articles/<slug:title>/<int:section>/', views.section, name='article-section'),
    path('weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
]
```

documentation :

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path